# How to rewrite if condition in groovy to Cypress?

Tags: if-statement, testing, groovy, cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

I have some front-end test written in Groovy and I need to rewrite them in Cypress.
I am currently having problem with rewriting an if condition to Cypress.If the popin window is displayed click on it, otherwise do nothing.

```
if ($(".PDialog").displayed) {
            $(".p-submit-btn.confirm").click()
            waitFor(2) {!$(".PDialog").displayed}
}
```

I have tried using a then clause. The current version that I have is this one  ```

```
cy.get('body').then($res => {
            if ($res.find('PDialog').length) {
                cy.get('.p-submit-btn.confirm').click();
            }
        });
```

but it is still not working as the upper one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Cypress.$` for `$`, and `.should('be.visible')` for `displayed`

```js
const $dialog = Cypress.$(".PDialog")

if ($dialog.length > 0) {
  // it exists
  cy.wrap($dialog).should('be.visible')  // is displayed
  cy.get('.p-submit-btn.confirm').click()
  cy.wrap($dialog).should('not.be.visible')
}
```

When using `.should(<some assertion>)` you automatically get 4 seconds timeout, so a wait is not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are a missing a point the class `PDialog`:

```
cy.get('body').then($res => {
   if ($res.find('.PDialog').length) {
      cy.get('.p-submit-btn.confirm').click();
      cy.get('.PDialog').should('not.exist')
   }
});
```